# ¿Como establecer conexión única entre servidor-cliente con SignalR en asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, websocket, signalr

Junto con saludarle, quería plantear el siguiente problema, resulta que utilizo signalr para mandar a imprimir a una impresora conectada en la red desde la pagina web lógicamente ubicada en el servidor, al computador del cliente. Cuando lo pruebo en un computador, funciona correctamente, pero el problema es cuando hay mas de uno conectado, me imprime por la cantidad de computadores conectados.

Este es el código que tengo en el html:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
var myHub = $.connection.myHub;
        var direccionWeb = $("#direccionWeb").val().toString();
        $.connection.hub.url = direccionWeb + "/signalr";
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            myHub.server.broadcastMessageToPrinterReportTicket(global_venta, global_mesa, nombregarzon, idgrupo, grupo);

        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
 });
```

En el HUB:

```
public void BroadcastMessageToPrinterReportTicket(String global_venta, String global_mesa, String nombregarzon, String idgrupo, String grupo)
    {
        string nombreImpresora = grupo;
        //resto de código para obtener datos.......

        String nombreRDLC = "report_ticket.rdlc";
        String nombreDataSet = "DataSet_ticket";

        Clients.All.imprimeReport(nombreImpresora, parametros, dt, nombreRDLC, nombreDataSet);

    }
```

En el cliente que es una aplicación escritorio:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    HubConnection hubConnection;
    IHubProxy hubProxy;
    //Install-Package HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp -Version 1.5.0.6
    public Form1()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
            IncializaSignalR();
            hubConnection.Closed += IncializaSignalR;
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        }

     private void IncializaSignalR()
    {

        String direccionServer = "https://mipaginaweb.cl";

        hubConnection = new HubConnection(direccionServer + "/signalr/hubs");
        hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;


        hubProxy.On<String, ReportParameter[], DataTable, String, String>("imprimeReport", (nombreImpresora, parametros, dt, nombreRDLC, nombreDataSet) =>
        {
            //Instrucción de código para imprimir con reportviewer
          }
        });
   }
```

Revisando el codigo, sospecho que la causa del problema debe ser la siguiente instrucción por la sentencia **All**:

```
  Clients.All.imprimeReport(.......
```

Por que al parecer, le envía la solicitud a todos los usuarios conectados, y la idea, es que la instrucción vaya solamente al PC del cliente que hizo la solicitud para imprimir, y no me imprima tickets duplicados(por cada computador conectado).

Me gustaría saber como podría solucionar este problema, no se si hay que reemplazar la instrucción All de Clients por otra, o en el cliente habría que finalizar la conexión por cada solicitud que se envié a imprimir y volver a re-conectar?
Cualquier ayuda, se les agradecería en gran manera.

Saludos

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522103/signalr-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-user-using-iuseridprovider-new-2-0

Comment: gracias por responder @Hackerman se ve interesante la solución, pero estoy tratando de obtener el id del usuario segun el ejemplo de la solución del link, reemplazando esto:
        var userId = MyCustomUserClass.FindUserId(request.User.Identity.Name);,
por HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, pero me dice System.Runtime.Remoting.Context no contiene una definicion para User. Me gustaría saber como poder obtener el id del usuario, y como lo recibiría en la aplicación cliente de windforms.